# Laravel 8 Does Not Delete Data From DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and now I want to delete a data from the DB, so I added this form:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy.question', $show->slug) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500 BJadidBold">Delete Question</button>
</form>
```

And here is the route for that:

```
Route::delete('questions/{slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'destroyQuestion'])->name('destroy.question');
```

And this is the Controller method:

```
public function destroyQuestion(Question $show)
    {
        if($show->ownedBy(auth()->user())){
            $show->delete();

            return back();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, it does not work out, I mean it grabs the `slug` properly but it shows **404
NOT FOUND** page somehow!

And I also tested this:

```
public function destroyQuestion(Question $show)
    {
        dd($show);
    }
```

But still shows **404 NOT FOUND** page, meaning that the process does not reach the Controller method `destroyAnswer()`!

So how can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

Comment: Your title is very misleading and in reality Nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: try to replace function destroyQuestion(Question $show) with function destroyQuestion(Question $slug)

Comment: @RiggsFolly hello, can you write what is the better title? thanks

Comment: Your route and method parameters need the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You are not Route Model binding correctly. You are trying to lookup the question by the slug, which is not the primary key. Laravel allows you to do this by prefixing `slug` with `question:`. Try this:

```
use App\Models\Question;

Route::delete('questions/{question:slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'destroyQuestion'])->name('destroy.question');
```